# FOSElastica + FosRest + Doctrine + REST Api

Tags: rest, doctrine, fosrestbundle, foselasticabundle, symfony-2.8

## Versions

- Symfony       2.8.2
- FosElastica   3.1.8
- FosRest       1.7.7
- Doctrine      2.5.4

## Problem

Hello,
I have some MYSQL's tables with many relations. I would like a build a REST Api, in HTMl a JSON, to get them.
It is working in HTML, but doesn't in JSON.
Indeed, in JSON I am returning array with multi dimensional, and doctrine made each request to get data.
This maneuver makes many times and fail.
The solution will be to make a SQL join with the return of ElasticSearch but I don't how to make that.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to make a REST API.

REST API never reterning a deep JSON Object, but only the asked object.

For instance one Entity People containing a list of Cars.

You have to make routing something like that :

Returning all users as light object (only id ans very important informations) :
/users

Returning one Full User WITHOUT his cars :
/users/{userId}

Returning full list if cars (as light objects) :
/users/{userId}/cars

Returning full car object (without sub object obviously) :
/users/{userId}/cars/{carId}

After you can manage your routing as you want with RESTFull